# Sending message/instruction from a governance system on Arbitrum to mint tokens on mainnet using Gnosis Zodiac Bridge

Tags: gnosis-safe, layer-2, cross-chain, bridge, arbitrum

I am working with a DAO that has their governance/voting system on Arbitrum, and their Gnosis Safe treasury wallet on mainnet.

The Gnosis Safe on mainnet contains minting keys to mint their native token.  I am trying to make it possible for voting on Arbitrum to trigger the minting of their native ERC20 on mainnet, and came across the Gnosis Zodiac Bridge app.

Is it possible to use Bridge to securely send a transaction from Arbitrum to the Gnosis Safe on mainnet to prompt it to mint more tokens?

If so, how would one structure it? I have considered creating another Gnosis Safe on Arbitrum as the primary DAO vault, and then making the Gnosis Safe on mainnet the avatar/controller? Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, you'd have to use an oracle.  You'd need something to return the result of a vote on Arbitrum to mainnet and then read the function.
A similar method for the Gnosis Safe wallets is the safeSnap which runs functions on a snapshot vote, but it's still not cross chain.

https://docs.snapshot.org/plugins/safesnap

Tellor has a zodiac module as well as more custom oracle queries that you could simply return the result from Arbitrum and run build an adapter to run the corresponding function.

Tellor Zodiac module: https://github.com/tellor-io/snapshot-zodiac-module

Tellor snapshot example (executing on off-chain vote, you'd just redefine the off-chain vote as some arbitrum vote) and you can define the action to execute on the returned result: https://github.com/tellor-io/snapshotVoting